# Defined Name to give text or date value instead of numeric value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, named-ranges

I had been trying out **Define Name** in Excel. I defined a name for a cell in which I would put a text or date value or I may leave it blank.

But when I use this defined name in another cell, the second cell shows a numeric value except when there is actual text in the first cell.

```
Value in first cell | Value in second cell
<blank>             | 0
Some text           | Some text
Date                | Numeric representation of date
```

[image: Samples displaying the issue with "defined name" feature]

How do I define a name for a column such that the value in first cell *(whatever that may be)* is displayed **exactly as it is** in the second cell? Am I missing something here?

***Edit:***
Upon suggestion of *mcalex*, I repeated the experiment with format applied (*Text* and *Date* as appropriate).

[image: Repeated experiment results]

The results are closer to what I need, but still not good enough. For example, even though the format applied works for dates, the blank text is still shown as a `0`. Short of resorting to a formula like *(pseudocode)* `if 0 then show blank else show text`, what can be done to fix this?

***Short Answer:***
Apply *Text* format on source cell (first cell) and the following *Custom* format on destination cells (second cell):

```
#,##0;-#,##0;
```

For dates, apply *Date* format on both source cell and destination cells. Please see the answer of *mcalex* for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **are** getting the *value* from the first cell - what you want is the *format*.  The results are similar to what you would get if you were copying the cells - as normal cells rather than named ranges - to cells that were formatted as 'General'.

When Excel sees the equals formula used on a cell, it includes the formatting.  This doesn't happen when using equals on a named range.

You may need to resort to some VBA that copies formats to achieve the outcome you are looking for.

Edit:

To have a copied/'equalled' cell not display 0 when the source cell is blank, you can use a Custom Format.  Select the cell with the erroneous 0 and change the format to Custom, and set the Type to:

```
#,##0;-#,##0;
```

This will set a comma separator, no decimals for numbers, will include a minus sign for negative numbers and set 0 values to blank.  This is probably not ideal, but should display correctly.  If you want to see decimals, set it to:

```
#,##0.##;-#,##0.##;
```

Comment: Please look at the edit to my question. Thanks.

Comment: The custom format `#,##0;-#,##0;` works great. **Thanks!**